# Selenium not able to input element in the form inside fieldset tag

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I have tried a different method to input elements like
**Here is xpath I used**

```
By NameOfTheProperty=By.xpath("//fieldset/div/input[@name='name']");
By NameOfTheProperty=By.xpath("//div/input[@name='name']");
By NameOfTheProperty=By.xpath("//input[@name='name']");
```

**Tried with Selenium Builder**

```
 WebElement element=driver.findElement(by);
        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        Action mouseOverHome = builder
                .moveToElement(element)
                .click().sendKeys(text).build();
        mouseOverHome.perform();
```

Tried with

```
 WebElement element=driver.findElement(by);
        element.sendKeys(text);
```

None of the methods is working..I can not able to input text inside the field and It shows

> Element not interactable

**Here is the site**

[image]

I hope someone help me to find out the solution..

Answer (score 1):

Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

xpath you should checks is :

```
//input[@name='name']
```

if it is unique,  then you can use Javascript executor :

```
WebElement password_input = driver.findElemenet(By.xpath("//input[@name='name']"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', 'password_should_be_written_here')", password_input)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Xpath is correct but unfortunately not working.. I think due to fieldset XPath not able to navigate the field. Some answer I found they use ancestor in XPath but not understand how to use it!! What you think? I am not sure how to use ancestor

Comment: I do not think so we should use ancestor. ancestor in XPath is to go to ancestor node from current node. Which you can do like this `//input[@name='name']/ancestor::fieldset `. having said that, we want to focus on input field.

Comment: You should also check if this input tag is in any iframe. or under shadow root. Are you really sure if we have the right xpath ? if it is correct, where is it located in UI ?

Answer (score 1):

personally I would use id's if the element has one.

```
"//*[@id='__BVID__104']"
```

Make sure you are waiting for the element to be ready.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
```

If it then times out on wait.until(... then I've found that sometimes an element must first be clicked for it to be exposed.

If this is the case. You will have to inspect the element before it is clicked. Find it's xpath, and see if it changes when it is clicked. If so then create a webElement for that element and have Selenium first click it, before clicking the actual field/element.